# How to set the "Copy Local Dependencies" in C# projects [problem with CopyLocal]

Tags: c#, msbuild, reference, csproj

I have an assembly called A.dll that has a **project** reference to an assembly called B.dll. The assembly referenced B.dll has a binary reference to C.dll.

A.dll --> B.dll --> C.dll

I've set at A.dll the "Copy Local" of B to true and I've set at B.dll the "Copy Local" to false of C.dll.

Anyway when I build A.dll I end with C.dll at the result folder. Why is not taken into account the "Copy Local" value of B.dll to C.dll?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because msbuild was *able to find* c.dll.  It doesn't know anything about the copy local setting of the B project.  It simply looks at the .assembly directives in the metadata of b.dll and sees that c.dll is a dependency.  And if it can find c.dll then it will copy it.  If it cannot find it then nothing happens, no complaints either.

The odd part, and your solution, is that c.dll is present in the same directory as b.dll.  How did it get there?  Just stop it from getting copied there and it won't get copied to the A build directory either. It is otherwise quite murky how you'd expect this to ever run.

Comment: It will run because what I'm building is a set on unit tests and the problem I'm facing with those references is that I'm getting application binaries inside the output folder where I should have only unit test binaries (that way the unit tests will run against the installed application at the target machine). I will check what you're saying, as usual it has been a great help.

Comment: Just as information we put all the binaries together at R:\ so that's why MSBuild can find them. :\

Comment: Do you know where can I find information about this behavior?

Comment: Yes, from stackoverflow.com of course.  Only some of the msbuild .targets file behavior is documented.  You could study them yourself to see what they do.

Answer (score 3):

That's because `CopyLocal` copies the referenced assembly *and its dependencies* to the output folder, *except if the referenced assembly or dependency resides in the GAC*.

Since you set `CopyLocal` on the referenced `B`, both `B` and its dependency `C` will be copied to `A`'s output folder, even if you did not set `CopyLocal` on the referenced `C` in the `B` project.

Note that if you build `B`, `C` is *not* copied to `B`'s output folder.

If you want `B` to be copied to `A`'s output folder but don't want the same to happen to `C`, one solution would be to put `C` in the GAC.

Comment: Crap, I cannot do that because I have this problem at our buildmachine and the buildmachine policies include not installing anything at the GAC. I really need a way to change this behaviour (with vcprojs I have not this problem because I can set the CopyLocalDependencies property to false).

Comment: @SoMoS, that might be a silly idea, but maybe you can remove `C` from the output folder during `B`'s post-build event, after it was copied?